# AngularJS directive model symbols with TypeScript interface

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

How do you initialize isolate scope for an AngularJS directive when using a strongly-typed interface?  If you want to use a model interface as well as the `"@"` `"="` and `"&"` binding symbols, it seems you confuse the compiler because you can't assign a string variable to properties with incompatible types.

For instance:

```
module widgets {
    'use strict';

    export interface IWidget extends ng.IScope {
        removed: boolean;
        onChanged: ()=>void;
        description: string;
        toggle:()=>void;
    }

    export class Widget implements ng.IDirective {

        public templateUrl = 'app/widgets/widget.html';
        public restrict = 'E';
        public scope: IWidget = {
            removed: "@",
            onChanged: "&",
            description: "="
        };

        public link: (scope: IWidget, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, 
                      attrs: ng.IAttributes) => void;

        static factory(): any {
            /* @ngInject */
            var directive = () => {
                return new Widget();
            };
            return directive;
        }

        constructor() {
            this.link = (scope: IWidget, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, 
                         attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
                var init = () => {
                    scope.toggle = this._toggle.bind(this);
                    scope.$on('$destroy', this.destruct);
                    scope.$apply();
                };
                element.ready(init);
            };
        }

        private _toggle() {
            // updated: this throws the type error
            this.scope.removed = !this.scope.removed;
        }

        private destruct() {    
        }
    }
}
```

Given the above code, notice that `onChanged` will produce compiler errors, because you can't assign a string "&" to a function.

You may get the following error: 
`2349 Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

Or this error on the `removed` property:
`2322 Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

In fact, even if you use `any` for the model the compiler still wont let you change the underlying type of a property after it is defined.

Is there any way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the **directive** definition.

It expects scope to be kind of `IDictionary<string, string>`, but type `any` would work as well:

```
export class Widget implements ng.IDirective {

    public templateUrl = 'app/widgets/widget.html';
    public restrict = 'E';
    //public scope: IWidget = {
    public scope: any = {
        removed: "@",
        onChanged: "&",
        description: "="
    };
```

The `scope` here, in the directive definition, is about describing how to handle **html** attributes *(passed as a `value`, or as `function` ...)* . It does **not** have type `IWidget`. That type `IWidget` will come into play when the scope **instance** is passed to `controller` or `link`

As said above, the `IDictionary` will work as well:

```
public scope: {[key: string] : string} = {
//public scope: any = {
    "removed": "@",
    "onChanged": "&",
    "description": "="
};
```

But the `any : {...}` and simplified notation will do the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A small tip ('any') helps me a lot with declare scope variable in my directive.

Answer (score 2):

> You may get the following error:  2349 Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

The main cause is that `scope` members need to be *stringly* linked (and one of the reason I am no longer an angular advocate).

The member `onChanged` should be callable just fine e.g. :

```
    public scope: IWidget = {
        removed: "@",
        onChanged: "&",
        description: "="
    };

    public link: (scope: IWidget, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => void {
            scope.onChanged(); // WILL WORK FINE
    }
```

You are probably misusing the annotation `IWidget` in your code (not provided with the question).

Comment: You are correct. Apparently, assigning `scope.removed=false` inside the link function works fine.  It is another function (not displayed) outside the constructor trying to set `removed` to a boolean that is the culprit.  I guess this turns into two questions at that point. I will update the code sample to show, but I guess I must be invoking it incorrectly.